# Two classes, same methods, one object?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a C# project making use of Oracle's "Siebel CRM" product. Siebel provides two namesspaces and classes that are used to programatically connect to it's services depending on whether you want to connect to the server or connect to a client session:

```
SiebelBusObjectInterfaces.SiebelDataControl
TWSiebelLib.SiebelWebApplication
```

SiebelDataControl exposes a specific method for explicitly logging in to a server based resource:

```
bool SiebelDataControl.Login(string connString, string userName, string passWord)
```

**All other methods are identical between the two classes..**

I'm currently maintaining two version of my application - one for each of the distinct connectivity classes. As the functionality that I build get's ever more inclusive and complex, it's becoming a real struggle to maintain both applications separately. I have split out the connectivity piece into it's own class, but I still have to copy and paste code between applications as I develop.

Ideally, I want a single VS solution that has one instance of all my custom code and some logic that determines which of the two connectivity classes to use, decided by the user.

Theoretically, I want something like:

```
class SiebelAppWrapper {

    public Object m_SiebelAppInstance;
    private Boolean m_isConnected;
    private short m_conType;

    public static short SERVER_CON = 1;
    public static short CLIENT_CON = 2;

    public SiebelAppWrapper(short conType) {
        if (conType == SERVER_CON) {
            m_SiebelAppInstance = new SiebelDataControl();
          } else if conType == CLIENT_CON {
            m_SiebelAppInstance = new SiebelWebApplication();
        } 
        m_conType = conType;
    }
}
```

But, for obvious reasons, the compiler isn't happy with this.

I'm quite new to C# and .NET development in general, so I'm hoping that there is some way for me to incorporate both classes without replicating all of the dependend code.

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't know enough to submit an answer, but if you're using Visual C# 2010, could you set the type of m_SiebelAppInstance as `dynamic`? As in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: @DanielRenshaw: There's nothing technically wrong with your suggestion, but I *really* wish `dynamic` wasn't billed as the solution to everything, jQuery-magic-dust-that-makes-problems-go-away style. It might look like it makes the problems go away, but you have to be aware of what you are signing up for.

Comment: @Jon I agree to an extent. Given what we know, I'd personally prefer your solution but we don't know everything about the OP's case and it's not necessarily the best solution in all cases. If `dynamic` could work then it may be worth indicating it as a possible solution for those that would most benefit from it.

Comment: @DanielRenshaw: Certainly, no argument there. My point was that swapping in `dynamic` is literally an one-word change that magically makes things work. Human nature being what it is, people will do it, move on and later wonder why their program breaks at runtime. Even worse, apparent success with the "make it `dynamic`" strategy will lead to the jQuery effect: there might be a good and easy classical solution for something, but hey dynamic works so who cares.

Comment: @All: Yes, I see how 'dynamic' can help: I've just tried it and it does allow me to do exactly what I want to do. I can also see, as others have pointed out, how it can lead to problems down the line. Thanks ever so much for all of your input as this not only helps with my problem but helps me learn best practice approaches for when I encounter other obstacles on my path to learning C#.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From your description *it sounds like* a workable option would be to:

1. Create an interface `ISiebelWhatever` that describes all the common functionality between the two classes that you are going to be using.
2. Derive two types, one from each source class, and make these new types implement `ISiebelWhatever`.
3. Use `ISiebelWhatever` as the type of `m_SiebelAppInstance`.

Of course this will only work if the source classes are not `sealed` and it won't help with methods that are not identical in signature. Furthermore, the common interface approach is somewhat obvious and this raises the question: is there any chance the source library already does this? Or perhaps the two classes share a common base? You should check first.

If there are methods that are not shared between the two classes but which you need to use, you will additionally have to decide on a common signature (declared in `ISiebelWhatever`) and make both of your subclasses implement it by appropriately forwarding to their existing non-shared methods.

Comment: If these objects are not passed into the Siebel API at any point then it may be possible to do this even if the classes are sealed. Just create a wrapper for each type where each has an encapsulated instance of the true object and delegates all the interface methods to the encapsulated instance.

Comment: @Jon: thank you for this. This sounds exactly what I want to achieve. I'm trying to learn C# in my spare time, so will need to make interfaces my next topic of research before I can try this out for real.

Comment: Just a quick note to say that Oracle do indeed already provide an interface - ISiebelCommonApp. Superb, thanks to you all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of method in common why don't you use inheritence or interfaces ?